# accessing variable from one file to another file

Tags: python-3.x, import, importerror

i am try to import a varaiable from sectionc.py to sectionB.py file.I have used import SectionC but it is giving an error of unresolved reference. How do i import the variable from File C to File B?

```
from SectionC import action #----------FileB

def action(max_prov_id):
    print(max_prov_id) #-------------Filec
```

I want value of max_prov_id to be accessed in sectionB file

Answer (score 0):

`max_prov_id` is an argument. You no need to import that. You should add `return` to the function and get the value by calling it.